# How to define the relationship between these 3 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 3 models like this-

```
| User       | Skill       | SubSkills    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| Name       |Title        |     Title    |  
| Trade      |Trade        |    Done(bool)|
```

What the models should look like-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :sub_skills
end

class SubSkills < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user #not sure
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

Basically skills are the same for every user of the same trade and one user has many skills. Each skill has many subskills but a subskill is done(or not) for a particular user.
Is this possible? Whats a better way to design this relationship? How will the routes be defined for this? Like which resource will be nested under which resource?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close, but try this:

```
class SubSkills < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :skill
  has_one :user, through: :skill
end
```

The routes could be done a number of ways: not nested, nested, shallow nesting ...etc. (check out [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), particularly section `2.7.1 Limits to Nesting`). It really depends on the needs of your application.

You could do something like:

`/users/:id/skills/:skill_id/sub_skills/:sub_skill_id`

..thus in your `routes.rb` you would have:

```
resources :users do
  resources :skills do
    resources :sub_skills
  end
end
```

If you want to be able to access all `sub_skills` directly from the user like `user.sub_skills` rather than via a specific skill like `user.skills.last.sub_skills` you would have to add the association to the `User` model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
  has_many :sub_skills, through: :skills
end
```

Comment: Will I need to put `User belongs_to :sub_skill ` ? Do I need to put a foreign key for user_id in subskills table?

Comment: No, and no. Unless you want to be able to do `user.sub_skills`.

Comment: If I nest skills inside users then when i create a new skill, i'd have something like `new_skill_path(@user)`, so won't that create that skill for just that 1 particular user? Whereas I want that skill to belong to every user with the same trade. But if I nest skills outside users then how will a subskill be marked done for a particular user?(because subskills is nested inside skills)

Comment: Is that case, you might want to look at shallow nesting. The resource nesting only effects the routs and URLs/paths to access resources. It does not control the model relationships. However, they are usually aligned in some way. 

So, really, you can do both. Have skills and sub_skills nested under a users for that user's relations, but also globally available for all skills/sub_skills. Read Rails Routing from the Outside In.

Comment: Yes I am using shallow nesting, but even in shallow nesting when you create a new item in a nested resource you need to specify the parent. How do I avoid specifying the parent?

Comment: Don't create it under that parent resource. You would only tie it to the parent if you need the relationship created that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88741/discussion-between-krishna-and-karl-wilbur).